# JS Digital Clock Displaying Only Tenths

Tags: javascript, clock

I'm trying to create a clock that displays time in the format we use to fill out time cards at work. It's a simple 6 minute increment 24-hour clock. For example, "1:30pm" would be displayed as "13.5".

I have no trouble creating a basic clock in either CSS or JS, and I can get it to only update the time on an interval, but I can't get it to convert/round up the minutes to the tenths (e.g. :30=0.5, :46=0.6, etc.).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `minutes / 60` is the way to go, don't forget to round this up with `toFixed` or something.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1):

Try using this code (JavaScript):
let date = new Date();
let time = date.getHours() + date.getMinutes() / 60;
let roundedTime = Math.round(time * 10) / 10;
You can try using Math.ceil or Math.floor instead of Math.round according to your need

Comment: let roundedTime = Math.ceil(time * 10) / 10; worked perfect for me, thanks!